# Optimizing a sed/tr shell script

Tags: apache, shell, sed, tr

I wrote a script to automatically add a ServerAlias to an Apache configuration file, then restart Apache, with a rather remedial understanding of `sed` and `tr` and probably shell scripting in general.  This is what I came up with:

```sh
cp /etc/httpd/sites/site.conf tmphost &&
sed s/ServerName\ site.com/ServerName\ site.com^#ServerAlias\ sub.site.com/ \
        tmphost |
    tr '^#' '\n\t' >/etc/httpd/sites/site.conf &&
rm -f tmphost &&
apachectl restart
```

Basically I'm creating a copy, replacing the ServerName line with itself + the new alias, using `tr` to put in the newline and tab (`sed` was being weird about that?), overwriting the old configuration file, deleting the copy, then restarting Apache.

It works, but doesn't really make mama proud, if you know what I mean. Any ideas on how to clean that up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add a ServerAlias line after ServerName line, why not use the 'append' command to add a line:

```
sed '/ServerName site.com/a\
    ServerAlias sub.site.com' tmphost >/etc/httpd/sites/site.conf
```

There's a 'tab' at the start of the extra line, which you seem to need.

If you have GNU sed, you can do the edit in-place with the `-i` option and without the temporary file (but don't use the `-i` option if the file you are editing has multiple hard links, and probably not it if it is a symlink, either; see the comments below from [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell)).

Note that you should wrap the code in:

```
trap "rm -f tmphost; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15
...script manipulating tmphost...
rm -f tmphost
trap 0
```

so that the temporary file is not left around if the shell exits because of a signal.  Of course, if you have an in-place alter, you don't need the temporary file at all.

Comment: On the other hand, what does `sed -i` do with the temporary file if it aborts for some reason?  Does it clean up the temporary file?  It is probably best to avoid `-i`.

Comment: I just got it working with `sed -i.bak '/ServerName site.com/a \
ServerAlias sub.site.com' /etc/httpd/sites/site.conf`.  Note I had to remove the s for the append to work.

Comment: Apologies — I'll fix the answer.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: interesting question, and one which I've not investigated.  There are several related questions: (1) Does it work correctly when the file has multiple hard links?  (2) Does it work when the name given is a symlink?  I assume that the people who added the `-i` option dealt with both those cases (and with interrupting signals), but I have not proven that.

Comment: `sed -i` definitely breaks hard links with gnu sed 4.1.2, which is the main reason I do not use that option.

Answer (score 0):

I like the way with direct ServerAilas addition using sed :

```
sed -i "0,/^ServerName.\+/s//\0\nServerAlias sub.site.com/" /etc/httpd/sites/site.conf
apachectl reload
```